# How can I parse this result?

Tags: php, facebook, json, parsing

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => query1 
        [fql_result_set] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fan_count] => 226 ) ) ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => query2 
        [fql_result_set] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fan_count] => 247 ) ) ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => query3 
        [fql_result_set] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fan_count] => 580 ) ) ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => query4 
        [fql_result_set] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fan_count] => 10 ) ) ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => query5 
        [fql_result_set] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fan_count] => 508 ) ) ) 
)
```

#### How I can parse this result ?

I searched, but I didn't found out how I could do it.

Comment: Format it correctly if you want an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array variable is called `$data`:

```
foreach ($data as $object) {
  $name = $object->name;
  $result_set = $object->fql_result_set;
  $fan_count = $result_set[0]->fan_count;

  // Do what you need to with the data here
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank lot !!   see =p  Array ( [0] => Array ( [like] => 226 ) [1] => Array ( [like] => 246 ) [2] => Array ( [like] => 580 ) [3] => Array ( [like] => 10 ) [4] => Array ( [like] => 508 ) )